# How to exclude a cache table from memcache?

Tags: 7, caching

I have created a one custom table for storing the data, based on cache rules i have created a table.

Installed and enabled [Memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) module in site.

Configured memcache in settings.php

```
  $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
  $conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
  $conf['memcache_stampede_protection'] = TRUE;
  $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';

  // The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned to non-volatile storage.
  $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
  // Don't bootstrap the database when serving pages from the cache.
  $conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
  $conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;
  $conf['cache_thrive_tips'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
  $conf['memcache_servers'] = array('localhost:11212' => 'default');
```

When i configure memcache in my site, at that time onwards my custom table(**cache_abc**) not storing any values.

How can i exclude only this table from memcache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it in the same way the  code you are showing does for cache_form.

```
$conf['cache_class_cache_abc'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
```

Adding that line in the settings.php file, you are telling Drupal to save the cache for cache_abc in the database.

Keep in mind that, in Drupal cache terminology, cache_abc (which would be the name of the database table containing the cache data, when the cache is saved in the database) is called *bin*.

Comment: you're code is working fine,thanks for you're help.

Comment: how can we configured for drupal 8

Comment: For Drupal 8, see [Cache API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/cache/8.9.x), in particular the part after _A module can define a cache bin by defining a service in its modulename.services.yml file as follows (substituting the desired name for "nameofbin")_.